# Update data with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsrender

i'm doing a project that have a social network like facebook, i need to update likes count without refresh (ajax) using jsrender, thats my code:

how can i replace the number of the likes that post have with ajax?

```js
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="postsTemplate">
  ...
<div class="feed-post-options">
  <div class="feed-post-buttons" data-postId="{{:PostId}}">
    <p class="post-feed-options" id = "postLikesCount">{{:PostLikesCount}}</p>
    {{if PostIsLiked }}
      <a class="small-icons-feed" href="javascript:likePost('{{:PostId}}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up like"></span></a>
    {{else}}
        <div>
          <a class="small-icons-feed" href="javascript:likePost('{{:PostId}}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up-checked like"></span></a>
        </div>
    {{/if}}

   <p class="post-feed-options">{{:NumberOfComments}}</p>
   <a class="small-icons-feed" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment comment" title="Comment"></span></a>
   <p class="post-feed-options">0</p>
   <input id="postIdValue" type="hidden" value={{:PostId}} />
   <a class="small-icons-feed" href="javascript:shareModal('{{:PostId}}')" name="Save" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareModal" onclick="shareModal('{{:PostId}}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share share" title="Share"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
  ....
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
   function likePost(postId) {
      var appUserId = $("#appUserValue").val();
      var request = 
      $.ajax("/Home/LikeComment", {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { appUserId: $("#appUserValue").val(), postId: postId },
               success: function (data) {
                 //how can i replace the number of the likes without refresh 
               }});
          request.done(function(jqXHR, textStatus){//just debug
              alert("Request done: " + textStatus)
              });
          request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
               });
       }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to modify the text content of the element:

```
<p class="post-feed-options" id="postLikesCount">{{:PostLikesCount}}</p>
```

and set the innerText to the new updated count.

Alternatively you can use JsViews to bind to the data (see http://www.jsviews.com/#jsv-quickstart), and then update the `PostLikesCount` observably - which will automatically trigger an incremental update of the innerText:

```
<p class="post-feed-options" id="postLikesCount">{^{:PostLikesCount}}</p>
```

or

```
<p class="post-feed-options" id="postLikesCount" data-link="PostLikesCount"></p>
```